# 'gradle clean' seems to kill my destination directory

Tags: gradle

I'm struggling with effects when combining a self-defined job with Gradle's `clean` job. Before going into any details here is the simple observation:

```bash
$ gradle clean; gradle myJob # works!
$ gradle clean myJob  # fails!
```

Running the second invocation with `--stacktrace` reveals a `NoSuchFile` exception.

Here is the gist of `myJob` (this is a slightly simplified version of the original job, taken from memory, so please forgive minor glitches):

```groovy
task myJob {
    doLast {
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("$buildDir/tmp1"))
        configurations.someConfiguration.collect {
            zipTree(it).matching {
                include somePattern
            }
        }.files.each { coll ->
            coll.each {
                Files.copy(
                    Paths.get(it.path),
                    Paths.get("$buildDir/tmp1", "foo"),
                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get that `myJob` uses a target directory under `build`, which is a directory `clean` recursively removes. After the combined invocation of both tasks, when the exception occurs, `build/tmp1` is provably not existent.

What I don't get is that the `Files.createDirectories()` call, which I was careful to use in the execution time block, seemingly does not create the target dir in that case. Or it does, and the directory is immediately deleted afterwards.

But running the combined invocation with `--debug` shows that the `clean` job is executed and terminates before `myJob` is started (At least according to the order and the time stamps with which the corresponding messages flow by).

So why is `build/tmp1` missing when copying starts?
What could I do to prevent this from happening?

[This is Gradle 2.3]

Comment: not a real answer to your question but: have you run a file monitoring tool to find out if the files  / directories are accessed in the order you assume when looking at the logfile ? On Windows you could use procmon for this.

Comment: @Marged Thanks for the hint, will try that.

Comment: your sample code is not working as Files.createDirectories() takes different parameters. If you can provide a reproducable example i can tell you what's going on here. My assumption is, that you try to create a file in the $buildDir directory before this directory is created. Remember that if you run your task as is with no other task invoked. the buildDir will not be crated for you and you must create it upfront. alternatively mark "$buildDir/tmp1" as task output directory so gradle will create it for you.

Comment: Also `myJob` task must be run after `clean` - configure it.

Comment: @Opal A simple `myJob.mustRunAfter clean` did not help.

Comment: I didn't say it would help. What I said is that it's needed to be configured.

Comment: @ReneGroeschke, @Opal I use `Files.createDirectories()` exactly for this purpose, to make sure the output dir is reliably created. But actually adding `outputs.files files("$builddir/tmp1")` to the task's config section solved it for me. But there is still a lot that puzzles me about this all. - If you guys care to cast your comments in answers I'll gladly upvote them. Otherwise I will add an answer of my own with my working version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @ReneGroeschke's hint about output directories, this version works in my environment:

```groovy
task myJob {
    outputs.files files("$buildDir/tmp1")  // <-- THE FIX

    doLast {
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("$buildDir/tmp1"))
        configurations.someConfiguration.collect {
            zipTree(it).matching {
                include somePattern
            }
        }.files.each { coll ->
            coll.each {
                Files.copy(
                    Paths.get(it.path),
                    Paths.get("$buildDir/tmp1", "foo"),
                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mind the additional `outputs.files` entry in the configuration section of the task.

A couple of things still puzzle me:

- The code behaves differently whether it is used in a `build.gradle` file verbatim or from a binary plugin that is 'apply'ed. (You need a few tweaks, like prefixing some method calls with `project.`, for the binary version.)
- I still need the `Files.createDirectories()` call in the doLast block. I expected that would be redundant now.
- Various applications of `.mustRunAfter` ordering when running multiple tasks did not help.
- The debug log (as described in the question) did not give any clue that the tasks were overlapping in some way.

Comment: does changing `outputs.files`` to `outputs.dir` resolves the problem of the need for doing "Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("$buildDir/tmp1"))" ?

Comment: @ReneGroeschke No, unfortunately not.